# Option to exclude files in pg_basebackup command Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, repmgr

When cloning a standby, how can I prevent pg_basebackup from copying postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf from the master to /var/lib/pgsql/9.9/data directory?

Currently I am using this command

```
[root@xyz..]# pg_basebackup -h {master ipAddr} -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data -U postgres -v -P
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[according to docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgbasebackup.html):

> The backup will include all files in the data directory and
>   tablespaces, including the configuration files and any additional
>   files placed in the directory by third parties. But only regular files
>   and directories are copied. Symbolic links (other than those used for
>   tablespaces) and special device files are skipped.

So there is no such option. If you still want to force it, move config files away from data directory (and optionally `ln` them to data_dir)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for Postgres 14. `pg_basebackup` takes backup of the entire data directory. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/app-pgbasebackup.html states that the backup utility will skip all directory/file that are symbolic links. So, that could be a workaround to get only desired content into the tar ball.

I had faced similar situations where I wanted to exclude the content of multiple directories like `pg_replslot,pg_dynshmem, pg_notify` etc. I made the tar ball the usual way: `pg_basebackup -D /backup/ -F t -P -v`. After the tar ball was made, and before restoring it to another server, I updated the tar manually by excluding content of all the required directories.